# whats wrong with my c++ regex match

Tags: c++, boost-regex

i am writing an robots.txt parser in c++

```
 boost::regex exrp( "^User-agent:\s*(.*)");

                 boost:: match_results<string::const_iterator> what;

                  if(boost::regex_search( robots, what, exrp ) )

                  {

                      string s( what[1].first, what[1].second );


                      cout<< s;
                  }
```

this should match the useragent with name * but it it returns all datas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the **double backslash** '\\' if you don't use c++0x raw strings.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to match *only* `User-agent: *` and not also (e.g.) `User-agent: webcrawler` you need

```
"^User-agent:\\s*\\*"
```

The * character has a special meaning, so must be escaped with `\`.  The `(.*)` in your code matches zero or more occurrences of any character and captures the match.

**Edit:** You also need to escape the backslashes as pointed out by *rubber boots*.